# Problem with spaces

Tags: spacing

I want to get this

[image]

My code is

```
\begin{align*}
[\delta(x)](i) & = x && (i \in M) \\
\sigma (f) & = \sum_{i \in M} f(i) && (f \in S)
\end{align*}
```

And I got this

[image]

And I get too much space, is there a way to correct this?

Comment: You can use `\begin{alignat*}{3}...\end{alignat*}`. For this you will need to add `\quad` (or some spacing) to separate the two columns. Also, don't use two separate display math environments.

Answer (score 3):

One solution can be using the `IEEEeqnarray*` environment from the `IEEEtrantools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rClL}
    [\delta(x)](i) & = & x                         & (i \in M) \\
    \sigma (f)     & = & \sum_{i \in M} f(i) \quad & (f \in S)
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To control the amount of whitespace between the two main "columns", I suggest you employ an `alignat` or `alignat*` environment. In the example below, the horizontal separation is set to `\qquad`; you're obviously free to choose another value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

With \verb+align*+:
\begin{align*}
[\delta(x)](i) &= x                   && (i \in M) \\
\sigma (f)     &= \sum_{i \in M} f(i) && (f \in S)
\end{align*}

With \verb+alignat*+:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
[\delta(x)](i) &= x                   &        & (i \in M) \\
\sigma (f)     &= \sum_{i \in M} f(i) & \qquad & (f \in S)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```